# JS input events executed in wrong order

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am investigating an issue in our web app, where a date change is not registered. Basically the user selects a date and then clicks on a 'save' button. I tried to reproduce the issue and get some weird results. I basically have two input controls: a date picker and a button:

```html
<input type="date" onchange="dateChange(event)"/>
<button onclick="save(event)">Save</button>
```

I simply select a date in the date picker and immediately click on the save button afterwards. This usually works correctly. Therefore my guess was that the issue only occurs on slow machines.

So I throttle the CPU by the factor 6 (I am using Chrome debugger on Windows for this) and set logpoints in both events. If I'm fast enough I get an output like the following:

```
button 1673970.2000000477
date   1674030.3000000715
```

Here the button event is fired before the date event. And even the event timestamps are in the wrong order. How is this possible?

*Note:* I can only reproduce this on sites with quite some elements on it. A test page with only the described two controls is too fast and always works correctly.

Comment: in reality, the timestamps aren't in the wrong order if the click event fires before the change event, if the events are firing in an unexpected order the timestamps are technically correct - have you tried this in a different browser?

Comment: @JaromandaX But the question is why the button click event is being triggered before the input change event. When you click on the button, it should first register the change in the input. He's not claiming inconsistency between the order and the timestamps.

Comment: @Barmar, `the event timestamps are in the wrong order` no, the event timestamps are not, the events arguably are, at least in Chrome, but not the timestamps

Comment: @JaromandaX I have now tried in Firefox. But as I cannot throttle the CPU there, the reaction is too fast, so I cannot tell, if the issue occurs there, too.

Comment: So, it could be a bug in Chromium based browsers - wait for the next release, they'll fix it - while introducing another two

Comment: @JaromandaX The timestamps are in the same wrong order as the events (1673xxx < 1674xxx).

Comment: @Barmar - clearly `timestamps are in the wrong order` means something different in your part of the world, where I'm from that implies that the times are in the wrong order

Comment: @JaromandaX Or maybe I'm just being stupid